# Why is my browser showing different color than I specified in CSS?

Tags: css, browser, colors, rendering

I have a web site which I specified `background-color: #005181;` using CSS.

If I open that page in browser and then check what is the background color using a [color picker extension](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/selektor-kolor%C3%B3w-i-narz%C4%99d/phillbeieoddghchonmfebjhclflpoaj), it is `#065181`.

If I use GIMP and pick color from screen, it is `#065082` picked from Chrome and `#064e84` picked from Firefox.

I've checked in devtools and the CSS color being applied is `#005181`, but it is being rendered differently on the page.

OS: Fedora Linux 39 (Workstation Edition)
GNOME 45.4 (X11)

Comment: What color is shown, when you open dev tools (e.g. F12 or RMB _Examine element_)?

Comment: The color in devtools is as I set. Even if I set the color directly on an element in devtools it is being rendered differently.